Build a Blockchain Tutorial - Front End Template stuck sending
Im pretty new to this whole thing, but I have managed to get a local node started and the front end template up. The Blockchain is finalizing blocks, and the template header is actively updating.
When I submit a transfer of funds the template indicates that it is sending, but then there is no further action.
I had to block polkadot.js from running to get the template functioning. Could the polkadot.js extension be inhibiting the template's functions?
I'm working in a Linux environment on a chromebook. I don't know if that matters?

in the front-end open the file substrate-front-end-template/src
/Transfer.js
Go to line 84 and change the transfer function to following:
callable: 'transferAllowDeath',
you can also get it from my repo here:
https://github.com/fzeeshan/substrate-front-end-template

I'm encountering a similar error. Could you please provide guidance on what edits are needed in the Transfer.js file available https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template? I'd greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you!

use my repo, it has the fix
https://github.com/fzeeshan/substrate-front-end-template

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
